# Failed to start HDFS service in Cloudera VM

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

When I am trying to start the HDFS, I am getting error:

> Service did not start successfully; not all of the required roles
>   started: only 0/2 roles started. Reasons : Service has only 0 NameNode
>   roles running instead of minimum required 1.

How can I go about resolving this issue? Due to this issue, I am not able to work on this Cloudera VM.

Comment: and how exactly are you trying to start the HDFS? Please, add the commands that you are running before getting this error

Comment: Can you copy cloudera agent log?